# Please help me to develop a cq 5.4 WorkflowProcess

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, aem

I am trying to create a `CQ` 5.4 workflow which updates the description of the Digital Asset Image which started this workflow.
My Problem is when I compile and build this code the WorkFlow Process does not appear in the Process Step's drop down in `CQ` 5.4 author server instance.

Here is the code , Let me know if any other step is required or I am doing wrong somewhere,

```
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Component;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Properties;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Property;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Service;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.day.cq.dam.commons.process.AbstractAssetWorkflowProcess;
import com.day.cq.workflow.WorkflowException;
import com.day.cq.workflow.WorkflowSession;
import com.day.cq.workflow.exec.WorkItem;
import com.day.cq.workflow.exec.WorkflowProcess;
import com.day.cq.workflow.metadata.MetaDataMap;

@Component
@Service(WorkflowProcess.class)
@Properties({ 
    @Property(name = "service.description", value = "Update the Image Description"),
    @Property(name = "service.vendor", value = "******"),
    @Property(name = "process.label", value = "Update the Image Description") })

public class RemoveImgPropBatchWorkFlowProcessStep extends AbstractAssetWorkflowProcess{
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RemoveImgPropBatchWorkFlowProcessStep.class);
    @Override
    public void execute(WorkItem workItem, WorkflowSession workFlowSesion, MetaDataMap meta)
            throws WorkflowException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        log.info("RemoveImgPropBatchWorkFlowProcessStep Workflow called up");
        workItem.getNode().setDescription("Image is updated");

    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to get this to work? How are you packaging the code? Is the bundle starting? Have you tried the examples here: http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/workflows/wf-extending.html ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Issue is resolved, all the dependent bundles were not active hence the workflow process was not getting displayed. Regards, Yash